# Error with Hive Query

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to run a Map Reduce Job with the following query,

```
SELECT  b.userId, a.movieId, a.title, a.genre, b.rating
FROM streaming.movies a JOIN streaming.ratings b
ON a.movieId = b.movieId
WHERE a.genre LIKE '%Adventure%' OR a.genre LIKE '%Children% OR a.genre LIKE '%Action%' OR a.genre LIKE '%Fantasy%' OR a.genre LIKE '%Mystery%' OR a.genre LIKE '%Thriller%' OR a.genre LIKE '%Drama%' OR a.genre LIKE '%Romance%' OR a.genre LIKE '%Sci-Fi%' OR a.genre LIKE '%Comedy%' OR a.genre LIKE '%Horror%'
LIMIT 10;
```

Hive throws an error,

```
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 5:6 cannot recognize input near 'LIMIT' '10' '<EOF>' in expression specification (state=42000,code=40000)
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Note: I have successfully run my job using 'RLIKE'. I am trying to workout with 'LIKE'. My 'RLIKE' version of code is,

```
WHERE a.genre RLIKE '.*(Adventure|Children|Action|Fantasy|Mystery|Thriller|Drama|Romance|Sci-Fi|Comedy|Horror).*'
```

Comment: You are missing closing quote after `'%Children%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running this query

```
SELECT  b.userId, a.movieId, a.title, a.genre, b.rating
FROM streaming.movies a JOIN streaming.ratings b
ON a.movieId = b.movieId
WHERE a.genre LIKE '%Adventure%' OR a.genre LIKE '%Children%' OR a.genre LIKE '%Action%' OR a.genre LIKE '%Fantasy%' OR a.genre LIKE '%Mystery%' OR a.genre LIKE '%Thriller%' OR a.genre LIKE '%Drama%' OR a.genre LIKE '%Romance%' OR a.genre LIKE '%Sci-Fi%' OR a.genre LIKE '%Comedy%' OR a.genre LIKE '%Horror%'
LIMIT 10;
```

You were missing `'` in `LIKE '%Children%`